# Host MP3 streaming website on raspberry pi

Tags: audio, web-server, streaming, database

I (as I am sure most people do) have loads of MP3s and CDs from pre Spotify days (other services are available). In particular I have quite a few that aren't on Spotify. So I have decided that I would like to have a convenient way to listen to them.

Does any one know of any software that exists that would let me store the MP3s on the raspberry pi (or an external harddrive attached to the pi), and then stream the MP3s from the pi to my phone (via an android app or a website hosted on the pi, so that the audio comes out of my phone).

I would also be quite happy to write the software myself, in which case I would like some advice about the best architecture. I am thinking something like a ruby on rails site (I say ruby on rails as I have used it *very* briefly before) + database, in which the MP3s are exposed as HTML audio elements. Is there something better to expose them as? Is there a clever way to put all of the MP3s into the database? Is there a better framework to use (nodejs? Mongodb?)? Is there a way to just expose the file structure in which the MP3s are stored?

Thanks!

Comment: [Here's a whole bunch of free and open source audio streaming server software.](https://github.com/Kickball/awesome-selfhosted#audio-streaming)

Comment: Thanks Chris, that is very interesting. I will probably try and do it myself (for the learning fun), and failing that I will try something open source.

Answer (score 3):

There exist some projects out there to achieve something like what you want. [Volumio](https://www.techjunkie.com/raspberry-piultimate-music-player-volumio/) is an example of that. Another one is [RuneAudio](https://www.maketecheasier.com/turn-raspberry-pi-to-hi-fi-system-runeaudio/).

Depending on where you want to store your music, I would suggest you review the official documentation to understand [how to connect an external storage device to the Raspberry Pi](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/configuration/external-storage.md).

I think the big challenges here will be to setup your

1. network
2. database: for this I would suggest using SQLite
3. (probably web) application: for this I would suggest trying out [Flask](http://flask.pocoo.org/)

Here is [an example](https://robertfilter.net/blog/webtech/flask-sqlite-jukebox-responsive-bootstrap-web-interface.html) by someone who used these technologies to achieve what you want

Comment: Thank you very much for the links. They seem to do the inverse of what I am trying to do (in which the raspberry pi plays the audio, controlled by the phone). When googling this is mostly what I find.